Resolution of instruction addresses to symbols in *86 linux ELF
I have instruction addresses from context-->[RIP] and I want corresponding symbols to them. I tried using dlsym but it does not work for static symbols. So, I tried doing it manually. I have to do it in code and cannot use any CLI utilities. Here's what I have tried so far:
First we get an absolute instruction address to look at from shared buffer. let that address be= 563174d510d5. Then we find starting address of that pid from /proc/($pid of engined)/maps. The maps contain address ranges in which our engined is mapped to. Let that range be 563174000000-5631763e0000. As we can see, our absolute address is within this range. So, we subtract the starting address from our address to get the offset. Offset= 563174d510d5- 563174000000 = D510D5.
3:13
Currently we are looking up this offset D510D5 in the symbol table. (looking means finding the closest function starting address of which it can be a part of).
Is there any additional calculations I am missing??. I am asking because the symbol resoltion from my algorithm and resoltion from addr2line are different slighlty. I feel I need to sybtract something more from the offset D510D5.
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0xd4aa20
There are 10 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040
                 0x0000000000000230 0x0000000000000230  R E    8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000270 0x0000000000000270 0x0000000000000270
                 0x000000000000001c 0x000000000000001c  R      1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x00000000023df318 0x00000000023df318  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x00000000023df400 0x00000000025df400 0x00000000025df400
                 0x0000000004afd048 0x000000000c6ec200  RW     200000
  DYNAMIC        0x0000000002415080 0x0000000002615080 0x0000000002615080
                 0x0000000000000270 0x0000000000000270  RW     8
  NOTE           0x000000000000028c 0x000000000000028c 0x000000000000028c
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  TLS            0x00000000023df400 0x00000000025df400 0x00000000025df400
                 0x0000000000000038 0x000000000006ea20  R      400
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x000000000218e464 0x000000000218e464 0x000000000218e464
                 0x000000000004959c 0x000000000004959c  R      4
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     10
  GNU_RELRO      0x00000000023df400 0x00000000025df400 0x00000000025df400
                 0x0000000000036c00 0x0000000000036c00  R      1


"I feel I need to sybtract something more ..." -- no, your algorithm appears correct. But the devil is in the details, and you haven't supplied any. You would get a better answer if you explain what makes you doubt your current computation.

Thanks for replying. My algo differs from addr2line. Example d53a20 corresponds to a functionA acc to my algo. But d53a20 is functionB acc to addr2line. And these two functions are very closely located. Also the values of symbols in my /sbin symbol table and the readelf or objdump on that symbol differe a little. The difference is not constant for all the symbols otherwise I would have subtracted it. Please show a way. I read on a blog we need to subtract ph->p_vaddr . I do not know what that is and how to get it in my code.

@EmployedRussian

"the values of symbols in my /sbin symbol table and the readelf or objdump on that symbol differe a little." -- that means there is a bug in your code (which you didn't show). That is the question you should be asking (show that code, explain that its output differs from readelf, and ask "where is the bug" ?).

I do not think code is wrong as it is a company wide code. Anyhow, any other tools in your knowledge like dlsym to acheive this translation easily? @EmployedRussian

"I do not think code is wrong as it is a company wide code." -- this is saying that you trust your company code more than you trust readelf. I can assure you that readelf is correct (and if your company code disagrees, is follows that your code is wrong). And no, there is no way to get to static symbols other than by decoding the symbol table.

Currently I am reading the symbol table. Any way I can execute readelf commands by a shell script and trigger that script from C code? @EmployedRussian

"Any way I can execute readelf commands by a shell script and trigger that script from C code?" -- sure: system(3) exists (but that would be the wrong way to do it -- the right way is to fix whatever bug in your code is causing the discrepancy).
